# Sensorless Drive

Tags: induction-motor

for my general electrical course I participated lab work about sensorless induction motor but for one part it requires to plot graph, I did not understand how to create this graph.Can you help me about it?
I observed autotune behavior, motor started after 5 sec, acceleration takes 10sec and frequency was 37,5 when it was accelerated, deceleration took 5 sec. [image]

[image]

Comment: From your problem description it looks like the axes should be frequency (Y) and time (X).  What more is there to say?

Comment: OK I made this graph but is invalid according to result of my report how can I fix it?

Comment: Well there are 2 discrepancies between graph and description. 1) You say deceleration takes 5 seconds but there's a 15 second slice of graph labeled "deceleration". 2) During that "deceleration" phase it is still getting faster. That can't be right.

Answer (score 1):

It should probable look more like this. There is no way to determine if the acceleration and deceleration should follow a straight line or some type of curve. Was there any time spent at 37.5 Hz or did it immediately decelerate after finishing accelerating as I show?

[image]